# rails override default getter for a relationship (belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, default-value

So I know how to override the default getters for attributes of an ActiveRecord object using

```
def custom_getter
  return self[:custom_getter] || some_default_value
end
```

I'm trying to achieve the same thing however for a belongs to association.  For instance.

```
class Foo < AR
  belongs_to :bar

  def bar
    return self[:bar] || Bar.last
  end
end

class Bar < AR
  has_one :foo
end
```

When I say:

```
f = Foo.last
```

I'd like to have the method `f.bar` return the last Bar, rather than nil if that association doesn't exist yet.

This doesn't work however.  The reason is that self[:bar] is always undefined.  It's actually self[:bar_id].

I can do something naive like:

```
def bar
  if self[:bar_id]
    return Bar.find(self[:bar_id])
  else
    return Bar.last
  end
end
```

However this will always make a db call, even if Bar has already been fetched, which is certainly not ideal.

Does anyone have an insight as to how I might have a relationship such that the belongs_to attribute is only loaded once and has a default value if not set.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

alias_method is your friend here.

```
alias_method :original_bar, :bar
def bar
  self.original_bar || Bar.last
end
```

The way this works is that you alias the default "bar" method as "original bar" and then implement your own version of "bar". If the call to original_bar returns nil then you return the last Bar instance instead.

Comment: You don't have a loop with that ? because call bar in bar ?

Comment: No, you call "original_bar" which is the new name of "bar".

Comment: One thing that tripped me up, was to remember to put the alias_method call BEFORE the new aliased method

Comment: For me this works, but in rspec there are `stack level too deep error`

Comment: couldn't line 3 be just `original_bar || Bar.last`

Comment: Work's OK for me in Rails4. Be careful not to call the method recursively (stack level too deep)

Comment: Better: `super || Bar.last`

Answer (score 39):

i found that using "super" is the best way

```
def bar
  super || Bar.last
end
```

I hope this helps you :D

Comment: This is such a great answer, as it just uses plain old Ruby inheritance. And it's a lot simpler than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

Randy's answer is spot on, but there's an easier way to write it, using alias_method_chain:

```
def bar_with_default_find
  self.bar_without_default_find || Bar.last
end
alias_method_chain :bar, :default_find
```

That creates two methods - `bar_with_default_find` and `bar_without_default_find` and aliases `bar` to the `with` method. That way you can explicitly call one or the other, or just leave the defaults as is.

Comment: Cool solution because you can use `_without_default_find` to have a notion of the original assocation method. Was the only one I was able to get working. Thanks

Comment: I believe `alias_method_chain` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon other answers here, you may also want to handle assignment operations as well.

Alias method:

```rb
alias_method :original_bar, :bar
alias_method :original_bar=, :bar=
def bar
  self.original_bar ||= Bar.last
end
```

Super method:

```rb
def bar
  super || bar = Bar.last
end
```

Where this was useful for me was when using `Bar.find_or_initialize_by` which meant the record wasn't always persisted, and also any non-persisted changes would reflect on the parent record as well.